# Unable to set named parameter with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

I'm using the CakePHP pagination helper with a custom route however it seems to be ignoring the page number. I believe this is because the named parameter `page` doesn't exist in the request, which I've verified using `debug($this->request->params);`:

```
array(
    'plugin' => null,
    'controller' => 'things',
    'action' => 'index',
    'named' => array(),
    'pass' => array(),
    'page' => '2'
)
```

As you can see, it's putting `page` outside of the `named` array. This is the route I've defined for the custom pagination URLs:

```
Router::connect('/things/:page', array('controller' => 'skins', 'action' => 'index'), array('page' => '[0-9]+'));
```

Obviously, this means that no matter what page number I click on only the first results show.

How can I modify the route to insert the page into the named parameters array properly? I'd rather not directly modify `$this->request->params['named']` from the controller directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the awesome documentation in the CakePHP Book:

> If you are planning to use custom named arguments with your route, you
>   have to make the router aware of it using the Router::connectNamed()
>   function. So if you want the above route to match urls like
>   /cooks/some_action/type:chef we do:

```
Router::connectNamed(array('type'));
Router::connect(
    '/cooks/:action/*', array('controller' => 'users')
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration

Comment: I've tried that already with `Router::connectNamed(array('page'));`, however it didn't make a difference. Also, that part of the docs also says you can configure it on a per-route basis which is what I did in the code snippet in my original post.

Comment: The code you have in your original post has nothing to do with named parameters - that's just doing regex for another (not named) parameter.